# Open thread in foreach loop

Tags: c#, multithreading, foreach

I am getting an XML feed and I parse it the my MQ server, then I have a service that listen to the MQ server and reading all its messages.

I have a foreach loop that opens a new thread each iteration, in order to make the parsing faster, cause there are around 500 messages in the MQ (means there are 500 XMLs)

```
foreach (System.Messaging.Message m in msgs)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[m.BodyStream.Length];
    m.BodyStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)m.BodyStream.Length);
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ascii = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

    ParserClass tst = new ParserClass(ascii.GetString(bytes, 0, (int)m.BodyStream.Length));
    new Thread( new ThreadStart(tst.ProcessXML)).Start();
}
```

In the ParserClass I have this code:

```
private static object thLockMe = new object();
public string xmlString { get; set; }

public ParserClass(string xmlStringObj)
{
    this.xmlString = xmlStringObj;
}

public void ProcessXML()
{
    lock (thLockMe)
    {
        XDocument reader = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
        //Some more code...
    }
}
```

The problem is, when I run this foreach loop with 1 thread only, it works perfect, but slow.

When I run it with more then 1 thread, I get an error "Object reference not set to an instance of an object".

I guess there is something wrong with my locking since I am not very experienced with threading.

I am kinda hopeless, hope you can help!

Cheers!

Comment: Which line throws the exception?

Comment: Don't start 500 threads.

Comment: Buy a 500-core CPU then it will be 100 % parallel, super fast and bug free. (In other words, your core idea is most likely false and fixing synchronization issues won't help you at the end of the day.)

Comment: Where do you get `Object reference not set to an instance of an object`? I think It should be more easier  you  debug your code than we try to guess what is going wrong. Is it possible that you get this exception in the code you are not showing us? `//Some more code...`

Comment: Here is the code: pastebin.com/cNtZE9g3 - I get the error at line 125

Comment: @IdoLazar, Don't you think to help to us in anyway. 1) you don't paste a link  so that I can click easily 2) Do you think it is easy to read your full code you are working on it for hours? days? 3) Are you sure `XDocument.Parse(this.OddService.InsertEvent(locationID, leagueID, startDate, homeTeamNameID, awayTeamNameID, sportID)` returns other than null.

Answer (score 4):

I note that you are running a bunch of threads with their entire code wrapped inside a `lock` statement. You might as well run the methods in a sequence this way, because you are not getting any parallelism.

Comment: I dont get it, sorry. what should I do?

Comment: Tell us in which line of your code you are getting the exception.

Comment: I have some code that used to parse the xml. e.g: int bookieID = int.Parse(reader.Element("EventMessage").Element("Header").Element("BookieID").V‌​alue); But I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", and all these elements are 100% set in the xml. I tried to remove the lock(..) but it still happens. the exception occur in the ProcessXML function. only when I am using more then 1 thread.

Comment: Put a test before starting the thread to see if ascii.GetString(bytes, 0, (int)m.BodyStream.Length) is not returning null.

Comment: put e.ToString() there and tell me what it prints.

Comment: I am making a check before call the function if its less then 10 chars, I skip it.

Answer (score 3):

Since you are creating a new `ParserClass` instance on every iteration of your loop, and also creating and starting a new thread every iteration, you do not need a lock in your `ParseXML` method.

Your object on which you lock is currently `static`, so it is not instance bound, which means, once one thread is inside your `ParseXML` method, no other will be able to do anything, until the first has finished.

You are not sharing any data (from the code I can see) in your Parser class amongst threads, so you don't need a lock, inside your `ParseXML` function.

If you are using data that is shared between threads, then you should have a lock.

If you're going to be using lots of threads, then you're better of using a ThreadPool, and taking a finite (4 perhaps) from your pool, assigning them some work, and recycling them for the next 4 tasks.

Creating threads is an expensive operation, which requires a call into the OS kernel, so you do not want to do that 500 times.  This is too costly.  Also, the min reserved memory for a threadstack in Windows is 1MB, so that is 500MB in stackspace alone for your threads.

An optimal number of threads should be equal to the number of cores in your machine, however since that's not real for most purposes, you can do double or triple that, but then you're better off with a threadpool, where you *recycle* threads, *instead of* creating new one's all the time.

Comment: Hey Tony, Thanks for the replay, I have some code that used to parse the xml. e.g: int bookieID = int.Parse(reader.Element("EventMessage").Element("Header").Element("BookieID").Value); But I get "Object reference not set to an instance of an object", and all these elements are 100% set in the xml. I tried to remove the lock(..) but it still happens.

Comment: @IdoLazar that's inside a `catch`. I need to know what threw the original exception?

Comment: Its line 125, I checked it using a debugger, and all the parameters seems to be correct, again, when I run it with a single threat, it works perfectly!

Answer (score 2):

Even though this probably won't solve your problem, instead of creating 500 simultaneous threads you should just use the ThreadPool, which manages threads in a much more efficient way:

```
foreach (System.Messaging.Message m in msgs)
{
    byte[] bytes = new byte[m.BodyStream.Length];
    m.BodyStream.Read(bytes, 0, (int)m.BodyStream.Length);
    System.Text.ASCIIEncoding ascii = new System.Text.ASCIIEncoding();

    ParserClass tst = new ParserClass(ascii.GetString(bytes, 0, (int)m.BodyStream.Length));
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(x => tst.ProcessXML());
}
```

And to make sure they run as simultaneously as possible change your code in the `ParserClass` like this (assuming you indeed have resources you share between threads - if you don't have any, you don't have to lock at all):

```
private static object thLockMe = new object();
public string XmlString { get; set; }

public ParserClass(string xmlString)
{
    XmlString = xmlString;
}

public void ProcessXML()
{
    XDocument reader = XDocument.Parse(xmlString);
    // some more code which doesn't need to access the shared resource

    lock (thLockMe)
    {
        // the necessary code to access the shared resource (and only that)
    }

    // more code
}
```

Regarding your actual question:

Instead of calling `OddService.InsertEvent(...)` multiple times with the same parameters (that method reeks of remote calls and side effects...) you should call it once, store the result in a variable and do all subsequent operations on that variable. That way you can also conveniently check if it's not that precise method which returns null sometimes (when accessed simultaneously?).

**Edit:**

Does it work if you put all calls to `OddService.*` in `lock` blocks?

Comment: Thanks! I get an error: Argument 1: cannot convert from 'method group' to 'System.Threading.WaitCallback' for this line:      ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(tst.ProcessXML);

Comment: When I remove the "lock" I get the same error, when I set the lock, it works, but only iteration by iteration, very slow..

Comment: "same" as in "same as in my original question" or as in "same as in my previous comment"?

Comment: same as my original question :)

Comment: I called it the 1st time just for a test, to see if I get something, I removed it now anyway. still doesnt seem to work :(, how can I check if its not a precise method? Its a webservice, I dont think something like that can happen.